# Duplicate Tag - event viewer

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag [event-viewer] and [eventviewer] are same

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-viewer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventviewer